# Strange Behavior using Solr

Tags: java, linux, windows, solr, solrj

After 2 weeks of investigation, I still have the same problem using solr.

My Document Collection : 3588 documents

Materials :

- My Computer :
  Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU 3GHz, 
  RAM : 4Go ,
  Operating System 64 bits : Windows 7 Professional.
- Virtual Machine (VM) :
  8 CPU
  RAM : 16 Go
  Linux

Sofwares on the VM :

- 1 Solr's instance
- Jetty
- java version "1.7.0_09-icedtea"

Sofwares on my Computer :

- Eclipse
- java version "1.7.0_15"

I've implemented a program with Solrj's classes under Eclipse to index my document collection dynamically (DYNAMIC). When I run this program on my computer with the ip address of my VM, my collection is well indexed (all my documents are indexed). But when I run the jar file of my program on my VM, i got a problem during the indexing, all my files aren't indexed.

I read my file with a BufferedReader class.

So, I have tested to create all my document in STATIC way to avoid to open BufferedReader and to avoid to parse my documents. And all my documents are indexed.

So, I wonder why it doesn't work when I use some Java Class ?

The different classes I use between the STATIC and DYNAMIC way are :

- BufferedReader : constructor, readline() and close()
- String : replaceAll(), split()
- Integer : valueOf
- File : getName()

Is it possible that there are some process differences between my both java versions when I use those classes ?

Plus, I've heard there is some differences between Linux and Windows to manipulate files. Is that right ?

Thanks for help.

Corentin

ps : I've witten another post linked to this problem : [Strange Behavior with ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409151/strange-behavior-with-concurrentupdatesolrserver-class)
I'm writting this new post because the other is a bit long ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

It was just a mistake in my code. My files were not read in the same order on my computer and on my VM. So the problem's causes don't come from Solr but come from me ... :-s